# I've detected a zombie.. now what?

Tags: ios, swift, nszombie

I have the following navigation flow in my app:

View controller A is embedded in a navigation controller.
A presents B modally.
Right before user dismisses B, the navigation controller's view controllers are set to: [A, C]
After B is dismissed, C is on screen.

Here's how the view controllers are set from B:

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let rootViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! RootNavigationController

let Ccontroller = UIViewController()

var newControllers = rootViewController.viewControllers

newControllers.append(Ccontroller)
rootViewController.viewControllers = newControllers

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})
```

A zombie is detected after pushes the back button on controller C.  The crash is inconsistent.  Sometimes I go through the navigation flow once, other times I go through the steps 15 times before receiving a crash.

I've looked through all the questions related to calling functions on deallocated objects and zombies, but most pertained to retain/release in Objective-C.  I'm looking for a Swift solution.

The most common crash log:

```
*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14b7d8880
```

A couple other crash logs our testers have found, which I believe are related to the same zombie issue.

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a780b0 objc_retain + 16
1  UIKit                          0x186617c88 -[UIImageView isAnimating] + 132
2  UIKit                          0x186605630 -[UIImageView stopAnimating] + 112
3  UIKit                          0x186605334 -[UIImageView dealloc] + 64
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a5eb54 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a6a040 objc_destructInstance + 92
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a6a0a0 object_dispose + 28
7  UIKit                          0x1869bae80 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 140
8  UIKit                          0x186604ce8 -[UIView dealloc] + 1436
9  UIKit                          0x18677fee0 -[UIControl dealloc] + 72
10 UIKit                          0x18677ffe8 -[UIButton dealloc] + 100
11 UIKit                          0x186a59474 -[UITouch .cxx_destruct] + 136
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a5eb54 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
13 libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a6a040 objc_destructInstance + 92
14 libobjc.A.dylib                0x180a6a0a0 object_dispose + 28
15 UIKit                          0x186643388 -[UITouch dealloc] + 72
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18142e384 __CFBasicHashDrain + 276
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1812e2bdc CFDictionaryRemoveAllValues + 352
18 UIKit                          0x186a51310 -[UITouchesEvent _setHIDEvent:] + 136
19 UIKit                          0x186606dd8 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 3984
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1813b0538 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1813affcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1813adccc __CFRunLoopRun + 724
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1812d9670 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
24 GraphicsServices               0x182bb0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
25 UIKit                          0x186671ec4 UIApplicationMain + 204
26 Slide                          0x100062a0c main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x180e768b8 (Missing)
```

_

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x24bfe690 CA::Layer::model_layer(CA::Transaction*) + 51
1  QuartzCore                     0x24bfe64d -[CALayer modelLayer] + 32
2  QuartzCore                     0x24bfe64d -[CALayer modelLayer] + 32
3  QuartzCore                     0x24bfe4e9 -[CALayer animationForKey:] + 56
4  UIKit                          0x26b0fbb5 -[UIImageView isAnimating] + 136
5  UIKit                          0x26afdee3 -[UIImageView stopAnimating] + 102
6  UIKit                          0x26afdc33 -[UIImageView dealloc] + 66
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22169f55 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22173e47 objc_destructInstance + 34
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22173e6b object_dispose + 14
10 UIKit                          0x26e99ccd -[UIResponder dealloc] + 128
11 UIKit                          0x26afd635 -[UIView dealloc] + 1428
12 UIKit                          0x26c7368d -[UIControl dealloc] + 64
13 UIKit                          0x26c73789 -[UIButton dealloc] + 96
14 UIKit                          0x26f2c2ab -[UITouch .cxx_destruct] + 126
15 libobjc.A.dylib                0x22169f55 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0x22173e47 objc_destructInstance + 34
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x22173e6b object_dispose + 14
18 UIKit                          0x26b3ae99 -[UITouch dealloc] + 64
19 libobjc.A.dylib                0x22184f67 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 150
20 CoreFoundation                 0x229f0058 __CFBasicHashDrain + 336
21 CoreFoundation                 0x228e1aa5 CFDictionaryRemoveAllValues + 276
22 UIKit                          0x26f264a5 -[UITouchesEvent _setHIDEvent:] + 120
23 UIKit                          0x26aff2ef _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 3366
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2298768f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
25 CoreFoundation                 0x2298727d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 452
26 CoreFoundation                 0x229855eb __CFRunLoopRun + 794
27 CoreFoundation                 0x228d8bf9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
28 CoreFoundation                 0x228d89e5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
29 GraphicsServices               0x23b24ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
30 UIKit                          0x26b68ba1 UIApplicationMain + 144
31 Slide                          0xccfbc main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x22587873 (Missing)
```

[image]

How would you go about determining what code is causing this?

Comment: Bring your gun,  and take a headshot.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the code for setting the navigation controller's view controllers.

Comment: I think answering this in the current form would be about as scientific as reading tea leaves. :) We need code.

Comment: Possibly the best title yet

Comment: @rptwsthi I was hoping a crowbar would be enough

Comment: Hey guys I saved his life :P Took his gun back from him :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this crash occurs when your ViewController is deallocated. Best practice to avoid this crash is make your ViewController as a property. Write getter method for it.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *aViewController;

(ViewController*)aViewController{

     if(_aViewController == nil){
           UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

           _aViewController = (aViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ViewControllerIdentifier"];
      }
      return aViewController;
}


 - (IBAction)pushViewController{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.aViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Avoid making instances of your ViewController in your navigation method. Just make a single reference and use it again and again. It might be possible while making new references again and again in your navigation method, your previous viewcontroller instance got deallocated.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll give this a try

Comment: sure also use it for the viewcontroller whom you are presenting as a modal